# Create new user and comparison for two textbox

Tags: c#, if-statement, textbox, try-catch

I have to do a form for new user in my project.
I do not know what is wrong with it.

This is the method:

```
private void NewUserMethod() {
    try {
        NewUserTbl newUserTbl = new NewUserTbl();
        newUserTbl.FName = txtFName.Text;
        newUserTbl.LName = txtLName.Text;
        newUserTbl.UserName = txtUserName.Text;
        newUserTbl.NewPassword = txtPass.Text;
        newUserTbl.ConfirmPassword = txtAgainPass.Text;
        txtFName.Text = "";
        txtLName.Text = "";
        txtUserName.Text = "";
        txtPass.Text = "";
        txtAgainPass.Text = "";

        if (txtPass == txtAgainPass) {
            DB_Admin.NewUserTbls.InsertOnSubmit(newUserTbl);
            DB_Admin.SubmitChanges();
            MessageBox.Show("new user created");
        } else {

            MessageBox.Show("Wrong Password");
        }

    } catch (Exception)

    {

        MessageBox.Show("You entered wrong data");
    }
}
```

I'm new at C# programming.

Answer (score 1):

You were comparing two controls instead of their text property

```
if (txtPass == txtAgainPass)
{

}
```

However if you start comparing with it's Text property

like this

```
if (txtPass.Text == txtAgainPass.Text)
{

}
```

this won't bring any change because you are making empty

```
txtPass.Text = "";
txtAgainPass.Text = "";
```

Try like this

```
if (newUserTbl.NewPassword  == newUserTbl.ConfirmPassword)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming these are textboxes : `if (txtPass == txtAgainPass)`. hence, they are different and not the same ...

try comparing the actual strings in them

Answer (score 0):

to get the text of TextBox for comparison or any thing ,
you should write " .text " after the name 
Like `txtName.Text`